# Delete files older than 5 minutes using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to delete only the files (*.txt) that were created more than 5 minutes ago in a particular folder. I've try something like this but its delete all *.txt files with no exception.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$path = "C:\Users\akoch\Desktop\Folder1"
$Extension = "*.txt"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include $Extension -Force | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: It might be better to work in UTC, e.g. `$limit = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(-5)` and `$_.CreationTimeUtc -lt $limit` so that the timezone and daylight savings time don't mess things up.

Answer (score 5):

Use -filter instead of -include

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$path = "C:\Users\akoch\Desktop\Folder1"
$Extension = "*.txt"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $Extension -Force | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit} | Remove-Item
```

The issue here is that you actually are not filtering anything